# PHP Register Successfully script is not working

Tags: php, mysql, scripting, scripting-language

After registering there is no "Registered Successfully" message and no redirection to `index.php`. Need help, please.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['save']))
{
  addcustomer($_POST['firstname'],$_POST['middlename'],$_POST['lastname'],
              $_POST['email'],$_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],
              $_POST['age'],$_POST['gender'],$_POST['barangay'],
              $_POST['com_address']);
  $success = "<script language='javascript' >
              alert('Register Succesfully')
              window.location='index.php'
              </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: are you echoing the $success variable?

Comment: i want to echo it but not realy good in php im new in it and learning PHP.. can u give me exact code of it that can run? and it will go to the location:index.php

Comment: just echo $success; it will echo the output to browser

Comment: tnx...problem solve.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to output **`$success`** variable

Either `echo $success;` or `print $success;` before the **`}`**